# How to update table even though it's locked by user

Tags: oracle, plsql, transactions, locking

I have an integration package that performs an update of ap_payment_schedules_all table. 
But if any of users hold inactive session with this table or ap_invoices_all,
the concurrent waits in queue to execute. 
I need to make this concurrent to be able to avoid these locks.
What should I add to my select?

Thanks in advance!

things below arent working out:

```
for update nowait
for update skip locked 

for blah (
select ... from table
union all
select ... from table);

update table 
set a1 = blah.a
where ....;
```

Comment: If a user holds a lock they hold a lock. You cannot work around the lock. What you can so is talk to your DBA about handling long-running inactive sessions and maybe killing them. Alternatively perhaps you can get a window of restricted access to the database.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to break another user's lock in Oracle, other than to kill that user's session via `ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '...'`.

That leaves you with just a few options:

1) Monitor your database while your program is running to make sure your program isn't waiting on locks.  You can get information about which sessions are blocking which other sessions out of `V$SESSION.BLOCKING_SESSION` and `V$SESSION.FINAL_BLOCKING_SESSION`.

*If appropriate*, you could then go to a DBA to have the blocking session killed.  Obviously you need to be sure who/what you are killing.  If it's just a user whose left their application open and gone home for the night, then it's probably safe.

2) Use `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE WAIT 3` (or however long you want) when acquiring rows to process.  This is sometimes done in a loop structure, like this:

```
FOR r IN ( SELECT rowid row_id, <other columns> FROM ... WHERE ... ) LOOP
  -- These are the rows we need to process.  Acquire a lock on each one before attempting.
  BEGIN
      SELECT 'x' FROM ... WHERE rowid = r.row_id FOR UPDATE WAIT 3;
      -- If you get here, you have a lock.
      ... processing ...
  EXCEPTION
    -- You'll need to define e_wait_timeout and associate ORA-30006 to it via pragma exception_init...
    WHEN e_wait_timeout THEN
      -- Record that the record was skipped so you can process it later.
  END;
END LOOP;
```

Answer (score -1):

Once a lock is acquired same can't be updated